# ASP.NET MVC 5 project with two or more default languages for different builds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, localization

I have a website, [website].com, that was written on ASP.NET MVC 5. My website is multilingual with the default language being English. The current structure looks like:

- Resources.resx // English resources
- Resources.de.resx // German resources
- Resources.pl.resx // Polish resources
- And so on...

I want to create a separate website for each country: [website].de, [website].pl, and so on. I am going to build deployment packages with config transformation and predefined preprocessors for each language.

Is it possible to use web.config or C# to change the name of default resources? For example, for the German language I want to replace Resources.resx with Resources.de.resx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx), it's the CurrentUICulture that determines where the ResourceManager searches for resources. So the easiest way would be to define a custom appsetting and in your code set the culture to that setting's value, then you can use config transforms to change that value. This is of course assuming you're not ever messing with the CurrentUICulture in any other way.